# NSMutableArray. Objective-c to swift code

Tags: objective-c, swift, converters

I'm trying to convert this Objective-C code to swift, but can't seem to figure it out:

```
@implementation MultiplayerNetworking {
    uint32_t _ourRandomNumber;
    GameState _gameState;
    BOOL _isPlayer1, _receivedAllRandomNumbers;

    NSMutableArray *_orderOfPlayers;



    #define playerIdKey @"PlayerId"
    #define randomNumberKey @"randomNumber"

    - (id)init
    {
        if (self = [super init]) {
            _ourRandomNumber = arc4random();
            _gameState = kGameStateWaitingForMatch;
            _orderOfPlayers = [NSMutableArray array];
            [_orderOfPlayers addObject:@{playerIdKey : [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].playerID, randomNumberKey : @(_ourRandomNumber)}];
        }
        return self;
    }
};
```

This is what I thought I would be, but I'm no sure at all, so I would appreciate som help here.

```
class MultiplayerNetworking {

    var _ourRandomNumber = uint32_t()
    var _gameState = GameState()
    var isPlayer1 = false
    var receivedAllRandomNumbers = false
    var orderOfPlayers = [AnyObject]()

    let playerIdKey = "PlayerId"
    let randomNumberKey = "randomNumber"

    override init() {
        super.init()

        self.ourRandomNumber = arc4random()
        self.gameState = kGameStateWaitingForMatch
        self.orderOfPlayers = [AnyObject]()
        orderOfPlayers.append([playerIdKey: GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().playerID, randomNumberKey: ourRandomNumber])

    }
}
```

But it gives me some errors, a lot:

[image: Errors]

I used this converter: [objectivec2swift.com](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/converter/) since I have no experience with Objective-C

Comment: Basically in Swift there are no implicit backing instance variables starting with an underscore. Remove the two leading underscores. And `uint32_t` is `UInt32`

Answer (score 0):

```
enum GameState {
    case waitingForMatch
}

class MultiplayerNetworking {

    var isPlayer1 = false
    var receivedAllRandomNumbers = false
    var orderOfPlayers = [AnyObject]()

    private let playerIdKey = "PlayerId"
    private let randomNumberKey = "randomNumber"
    private var ourRandomNumber = arc4random()
    private var gameState = GameState.waitingForMatch


    init() {
        orderOfPlayers.append([playerIdKey: GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer.playerID, randomNumberKey: ourRandomNumber] as AnyObject)
    }

}
```

I am assuming that `GameState` is an enum, and have made the `enum` with just the one case I can see from your code. I am also guessing that variables starting with an underscore are supposed to be private instance variables of that class, so I have made them `private` here. Instead of initializing everything in `init`, I have made use of Swift to give all the properties initial values.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MultiplayerNetworking {

        var _ourRandomNumber = [__uint32_t]()
        var _gameState = GameState()
        var isPlayer1 = false
        var receivedAllRandomNumbers = false
        var orderOfPlayers = [AnyObject]()
        let playerIdKey = "PlayerId"
        let randomNumberKey = "randomNumber"

                 init() {

                            self.ourRandomNumber = arc4random()
                            self.gameState = kGameStateWaitingForMatch
                            self.orderOfPlayers = [AnyObject]()
                            orderOfPlayers.append([playerIdKey: GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().playerID, randomNumberKey: ourRandomNumber])

                  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this code

```
class Player{
   var playerIdKey : String?
   var randomNumberKey : UInt32?
}

class MultiplayerNetworking {

var ourRandomNumber = UInt32()
var gameState = GameState()
var isPlayer1 = false
var receivedAllRandomNumbers = false
var orderOfPlayers = [Player]()

let playerIdKey = "PlayerId"
let randomNumberKey = "randomNumber"

override init() {
    self.ourRandomNumber = arc4random()
    self.gameState = kGameStateWaitingForMatch
    let player = Player()
    player.playerIdKey = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().playerID
    player.randomNumberKey = ourRandomNumber
    orderOfPlayers.append(player)
}
}
```

I would recommend that you create a separate class for player in the previous code the variable was an array type of AnyObject and a tipple was being appended to it so the compiler was complaining. So create a separate player class and set its properties and then append it to your array and your code should run fine.I also removed override keyword from init as there is no super class for this class.

Comment: Since you're not inheriting from anything you shouldn't be able to call `super.init()`

Comment: It gives me an error at `orderOfPlayer.append([play...`. The error is 'Contextual type 'anyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal'